# Opening multiple files with ifstream in a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, ifstream

I was wondering if I could do the following.
I'm trying to open multiple files in a recursive function.

```
void openFile(Node* n, string file) {
    ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open(file.c_str());
    string command;

    while(ifile >> command) {
        if(...) {

        ...

        } else if(command == "blah") {
            ifile >> command;
            executeFile(n, command);
        }
    }

    ifile.close();
    return;
}
```

I wrote such function, but I'm keep getting the following error when testing in unix:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I was wondering if this is caused by my opening file function.
What could be the problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try using a debugger to figure out what the issue is, or at least get some more detailed error information and preferably a line number of the crash. It's very hard to answer for us, the way this is posted now.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using locals in recursive functions. Likely you're getting a stack overflow (too deep recursion) or otherwise running out of resources. Try debugging the code

Comment: As said, there's nothing wrong with using recursion. What you probably WILL run into is the limit on the number of file descriptors, which you can check with `ulimit -n`. To determine why you get a segmentation fault we'd need more code.

Comment: Yes, I've figured the error was caused from other part of the program. Thank you!